# Checking long algebraic manipulations

Tags: soft-question

I have to do a lot of long calculations lately. Most often signs go missing or I miss some constants or forget some terms altoghether. Is there some good strategy to prevent that? I tried repeating the calculations, checking for unit consistency, or some physics checks. Are there other tried and true strategies.

Comment: I removed a number of comments that appeared to be answering the question. Please remember that comments are meant for suggesting improvements or requesting clarifications, not for answering. (Also, I'm looking into whether this would be suitable on [academia.se].)

Comment: We had a discussion between moderators of different sites and arrived at the conclusion that this kind of question would be best suited for [math.se]. However, the question is very broad as it stands, as it is 1) covering several types of mistakes 2) you do not clarify on what level this is happening (homework vs. ready-to-publish research) or how much effort you are willing to invest, respectively. Thus, we would recommend that you ask a more specific question on [math.se]. (You can ask questions about other types of errors later if this goes well.) PS: An example would probably also help.

Comment: A more focused question might be better on [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's actually about research calculations. Long means ten-hundred pages long manipulations, and some simply aren't easy to automate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this problem has any easy answers, other than learning by experience how you can structure your calculations in ways that will minimize the friction with fiddly algebraic manipulations where mistakes are more likely.

For many situations, though, I find numerical checks are very often helpful in helping catch mistakes early. Thus, if you're e.g. attempting a complicated special-functions integration of some complicated integrand in exact terms, you can have a calculation on the side (say, a Mathematica notebook), where you regularly benchmark any derivative expressions for your initial left-hand side against a numerical integration of whatever it is you started with. Running this regularly (read: pretty much at every line in the calculation) increases the chance that you will catch any mistakes early and before they propagate into other places.